# Multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to create a multi-dimensional array with two variables but don't know how.

This is what i have so far;

```
 $_SESSION['name'][] = $row_subject['name'];
 $_SESSION['history'][]= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I wanted to know if this is possible?

```
$_SESSION['name'][] = $row_subject['name'],$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

i want to get the name of a programme which is generated via a data base and also to retrieve the url. What i am actually doing once the name is retrieve, i want to make that a link which the url would be necessary.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. We don't know exactly what you want.  We need a [mcve].  Should `$_SESSION['name']` have a count of 1 because it contains an array containing two elements? Or should it have a count of 2 because you merely wanted to push two elements into it separately?  We cannot be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do but the correct notation for your second example could be

```
$_SESSION['name'][] = array("name" => $row_subject['name'], 
                            "history" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This pushes an associative array with the keys "name" and "history" to the array $_SESSION["name"].

You could then access the entries like so:

```
echo $_SESSION["name"][0]["name"];
echo $_SESSION["name"][0]["history"];
```

if you repeat the command with different data:

```
$_SESSION['name'][] = array("name" => $row_subject['name'], 
                            "history" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

the next entry would be addressed like so:

You could then access the entries like so:

```
echo $_SESSION["name"][1]["name"];
echo $_SESSION["name"][1]["history"];
```

and so on.

Comment: would i be able to pull the values separately in a foreach.
this is what i had.

     foreach($_SESSION['name'] AS $urls) { 
        echo"<li>$urls</li><hr/>";     
     }

would this be done?

Comment: If you follow the example above, it would have to be `foreach($_SESSION['name'] AS $urls) { echo"<li>".$urls["history"]."</li><hr/>"; }`. Whether this structure makes sense, only you can decide.

Comment: ok. This is what is did:

    $_SESSION['name'][] = array("name" => $row_subject['name'], "history" => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if(empty ($_SESSION['name'])){
       echo "";
      }
      else{
       $name=$_SESSION['name'];
       krsort($name);      
       foreach(array_unique(array_slice($name, 0, 5)) AS $urls) { 
        echo"<li>".$urls["name"]."</li><hr/>";        
       }
      }
this however is only returning one item at a time. i would like to return like about top 5 recent items. how can i do this?

Comment: @pundit as far as I can see, if the name array contains items, the way you do it should be perfectl y fine , and not return only one item. Can you confirm how many items are in the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['name'][] = array($row_subject['name'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```